# How to make UITextField appear with Swift Code

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make the following UITextField appear when I compile and run the application. I have the UITextField declared and initialised as:

```
var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 40.00));
```

However when I run the app, this text field does not appear. What Swift code would make the textfield appear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to actually add the text field to the view hierarchy, which is done slightly differently depending on the class that you're in. If for example, you're in a UIViewController subclass, you add it as a subview of the UIView attached to the view controller's view property.

```
var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 40.00));
self.view.addSubview(myTextField)
```

Or, if you're working with a subclass of UIView, you could use:

```
self.addSubview(myTextField)
```

After you've added your text field to the view hierarchy, it's still possible that you won't be able to see it. By default, text field will have a white background color, no text, and no border around it. This can all be changed through use of the following properties.

```
myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
myTextField.text = "some string" 
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
```

Comment: I have added that to the code, yet the text field is still not appearing when I run the app. I am inside UIViewController.

Comment: @StephenFox It probably is on screen and you just can't see it. Try adding text to the textfield, or setting the background color to something other than white to be able to see it. `myTextField.text = "some string"` or `myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Comment: @StephenFox You should also change the bordStyle of the text field. I believe it's none by default when instantiated this way. `myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this `UITextField` as a subview of another `UIView`.

Assuming you are inside a `UIViewController`, you could call `self.view.addSubview(myTextField)`.